# Does Ruse consist of two campaigns?

Tags: ruse

I just finished the Allied campaign in the RTS game, [Ruse](http://ruse.uk.ubi.com/). After completing the campaign I read its [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=R.U.S.E.&oldid=385123152), which states:

> There are two campaigns in the game
>   […] The second takes place from the
>   point of view General Major Erich Von
>   Richter in the Wehrmacht, whose dreams
>   of military perfection on the
>   battlefield were realized with the
>   invention of Blitzkrieg. The game
>   follows General Richter who, while
>   battling allied generals, is trying to
>   uncover a traitor in the upper ranks
>   of his command.

That paragraph is quoted from the games official site.

The [review on the site NZGamer](http://nzgamer.com/pc/reviews/1160/r-u-s-e.html) states:

> The second campaign storyline allows
>   you to have a decent crack at a German
>   storyline […]

I haven't managed to find this campaign, and can't find anything about it any other place. Are there really two campaigns within this game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It [appears that this is false](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1436060).  Perhaps the developers were forced to make cuts and marketing never caught up?